# I want to run a kernel-based VM using the command line with as minimal a set of packages as possible, how do I do this?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

What are the minimal set of additional packages (over a basic server install) I would need on Ubuntu Server 20.04 to run a KVM (for argument's sake lets say it's a virtualized instance of Ubuntu 20.04)?

I basically want to run KVM on the command-line, for some reason most of the guides I have found only deal with using virt-manager and I want to avoid using a GUI.

Comment: KVM hypervisor: a beginners’ guide https://ubuntu.com/blog/kvm-hyphervisor

Comment: see [the Ubuntu Serverguide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-virt-tools), scroll down to the `virt-install` section.